# UIScrollview - Off-screen buttons do not fire

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview that is very long and exceeds the width of the screen.  See the below screenshot for reference.

[image: example drawing]

I am programatically adding buttons to this scrollview in a dynamically-varying for-loop.  There is a "containerView" that basically is the same width of the scrollview, and I'm actually adding the buttons directly onto that.  The code is pretty straight-forward there, something like the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++) {
    UIButton *currentButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [currentButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [currentButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [currentButton setTag:i];
    [currentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.containerView addSubview:currentButton];
    // here's where I programatically set constraints for positioning
}
```

The buttons show perfectly fine in the correct spots, and the ones initially on the screen (i.e. the first 2 in the screenshot example above) fire the "buttonPressed:" method perfectly fine.  However, the ones that are initially off-screen still show fine, but the event is not fired when tapped.

I see other similar posts to this out there, but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas on where to go on this one?  I'm a bit stumped.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the buttons enter the highlighted state?

Comment: Good question, the ones initially on the screen do indeed enter the highlighted state as I press them, but the ones off screen do not.

Comment: This is usually caused by the buttons being outside the bounds of their superview. You should give containerView a background color to see if this is true.

Comment: Bingo!!  I set the background of the containerView to white, and voila, when I scrolled to the right, the white ended at the exact point of the screen's edge.  Now I need to find a fix to make that size appropriately.  Thank you for your answer on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this turned out to be exactly what rdelmar indicated in his comment.  The containerView's frame was being set to the bounds of the screen size, so when I changed the background color to white, it became obvious that the bounds were limited to the initial screen width.

The fix was pretty simple - once the for-loop completed, I knew exactly how long the containerView needed to be, so I just set the frame there to the appropriate width.  Issue resolved!

Answer (score 0):

After your for loop you need to ensure you are setting the content size of the scrollview

`[self.containerView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(MAX_X_FROM_LAST_BUTTON, self.containerView.frame.size.height)];`

Comment: I did confirm that the contentSize of the scrollview is being set appropriately.  I even logged it to be sure (see below).  However, I'm setting the contentSize BEFORE I go through the loop and add the buttons to it.  I would think that shouldn't make a difference, but I wanted to be sure, since you mentioned that it should be done AFTER the for-loop?

contentsize: 4813.000000,152.000000

Comment: I'm not sure, the only reason I mentioned this is because you'd not included it in your code snippet. Have you tried setting the contentSize afterwards to see if it makes difference?